# Parse query multiple key swift in queryForTable()

Tags: swift, uitableview, parse-platform, uisearchbar

I use Parse in order to manage my database.

I have a tableView with a searchBar.
It's working very well.

My function about the query is the following :

```
override func queryForTable() -> PFQuery {
    var query = PFQuery(className: "students")
    if searchBar.text != "" {
        query.whereKey("prenom", containsString: searchBar.text.uppercaseString)
    }
    query.orderByAscending("prenom")
    return query
}
```

This works very well.

But now I want to add multiple key into my research, like :

```
query.whereKey("prenom", containsString: searchBar.text.uppercaseString)
query.whereKey("nom", containsString: searchBar.text.uppercaseString)
```

But this code, and it is normal, do : "I want searchBar.text IN prenom AND nom"
And that's not what I want.
I want to search for exemple : "John", and this result has to be "john" in "prenom" OR in "nom".

I don't know how to return a PFQuery with multiple keys into the query.

Does someone have an idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do an `OR` query in Parse you need to use the [Compound Query](https://www.parse.com/docs/ios/guide#queries-compound-queries) functionality. You construct two independent queries, then use the `orQueryWithSubqueries` method on `PFQuery`. For your example...

```
override func queryForTable() -> PFQuery {
  var query: PFQuery!
  if searchBar.text != "" {
    var prenomQuery = PFQuery(className: "students")
    var nomQuery = PFQuery(className: "students")
    prenomQuery.whereKey("prenom", containsString: searchBar.text.uppercaseString)
    nomQuery.whereKey("nom", containsString: searchBar.text.uppercaseString)
    query = PFQuery.orQueryWithSubqueries([prenomQuery, nomQuery])
  } else {
    query = PFQuery(className: "students")
  }
  query.orderByAscending("prenom")
  return query
}
```

I don't recall if the result set is uniqued (lets say someone has the search text in both their nom and prenom fields), so you should check that out.

Comment: It works well for what I ask ! And what if I want to search with multiple keywords, for example I want to search for "Sarah Crosh" (firstname, lastname) ? So I need to creat queries for each words ...

Comment: You'll need to add extra where constraints to your query, so something like `query.whereKey("firstname", equalTo: "Sarah")` and then `query.whereKey("lastname", equalTo: "Crosh")`

Answer (score 0):

What I finally did is creat another column in my table and concatenate all my searchable information.

Then I do the same, I search my searchBar.text in this column, with containsString.

It works almost perfectly, the only issue I found is if I want to search in the reverse order of the string in my new column.